# Authorize request between web services by Single Access Token using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: .net, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to implement authentication using oAuth and using DotNetOpenAuth for this.

We have multiple REST web services to cater project requirement. There is one AuthenticationService, Customer Service, Order Service etc.

Consumer will authenticate the users using this Service and get Access Token from it. Now Consumer will a method on Customer Service and pass Access token.

Customer Service now wants to validate Access Token from Authentication Service.

I tried to capture Authorization Header sent by Consumer in Customer Service and tried to pass this to Authentication Service from Customer Service but it threw "signature not valid" error which seems correct because the URI used by consumer to build signature is of Customer Service but while validating this in Authentication Service actual request comes from Customer Service which is a different one.

Hope I am able to explain the problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using OAuth 1.0.  And it sounds like you're forwarding the OAuth authorization from the customer service to the authentication service, in such a way that the authentication service believes the token was intended for *it* instead of the customer service.  If so, then this invalid signature is by design, because you're effectively (and accidentally) conducting an attack whereby a MITM redirects the token to another service.

Each service must verify the access token for itself -- it can't forward it to another service.  Each service can do this by sharing the `ITokenManager`'s database with the authentication service.

Comment: I do not want to share token database between service. So now, here is what I trying to do. I assigned consumer key and secret to each web service. On Application Start web service will authenticate itself. Consumer will send Access_token and its consumer key to Customer Service which in turns will call Authentication Service to verify access token and consumer's key.

Comment: Customer Service authentication at Application_Start worked when I tested with WebDev Server under IDE but when hosting in IIS 7 it failed and returned error "Response is not available in this context". I tried to move this code in Application_BeginRequest so that I can authenticate service on the call if it is already not. But this also failed. Any help on how can I do this?

Comment: I don't follow your new design.  But if you don't want to share your token database, then you should strongly consider OAuth 2, which supports that scenario.

Comment: I am looking at the Samples for oAuth2.0. The sample OAuthAuthorizationServer library uses OpenId but I want to provide my own implementation here. Moreover for now I just want validate the consumer application return Access token and then use resource server to access resources. How can this be done?

Comment: The authorization server's means of authenticating the user is orthogonal to OAuth authorization.  So by all means you can use your own implementation for that.  I'm confused by your "consumer application return access token" statement.  Consumers don't return access tokens.  They obtain them from authorization servers.